# Slow down sliding animation between android activities?

Tags: android, animation, android-activity

I know that android automatically uses sliding animations if you open and close activities. Then they slide from left to right and fill the screen (or from right to left).
The thing is that the animation is quite fast... it is visible on the emulator but it is barely noticeable on the phone itself. I am wondering if there is any way to slow down this animation so it would definitely be seen that the view is sliding.

Comment: I'd like to add something. The animation between activities lasts as long as needed to create the Activity you're navigating to, it is actually a nice-looking loading-screen. And of-course, altering loading time is something not done.
It is possible to override the default animation though. Define an animation in Xml and do `Activity.overridePendingTransition()`, here's a [complete tutorial](http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=343) on Xml-animations.
However I don't think it's not possible to alter the default animation (as far as I know). And, the default one is not the same on all devices.

Answer (score 3):

First prevent the default animation (Slide in from the right) with the `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION` flag in your intent.

ie.,

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class);
myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
context.startActivity(myIntent);
```

Now you can load your own custom animation. Refer this [link](http://blog.blundell-apps.com/animate-an-activity/) to know how to animate your activity's in and out.

Answer (score 1):

you can specify the duration of the animation in your animation `.xml` in `res/anim` for example for sliding out left:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shareInterpolator="false" >

 <translate
    android:duration="500"
    android:fromXDelta="0%"
    android:fromYDelta="0%"
    android:toXDelta="-100%"
    android:toYDelta="0%" />

</set>
```